# Making the font from a form bigger

Tags: html, css, button, text

again me and my stupid problems.
Now I got the following page:

http://jsfiddle.net/g3VBT/

I want to make the "enter your U.R.L here" text the following properties:

**font-weight: 600;

font-size: 1.5em;**

The problem is,if I edit the font-size,the whole box looks wrong.
Is there ani solution to this?
Thanks!

Comment: Fix your markup and CSS first, using a markup validator and the W3C CSS Validator. Then describe what you actually want, instead of just saying “looks wrong”.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by wrong? Try and decrease the padding.

Comment: I want the button size remain the same...
Go out and try to make the font 1.5em and see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you raise the font-size, the width will also rise. reduce the value to e.g.20em or less, and then you can put the font-size to 1.5em.

It would be easier to understand your question if you would present a "This is how it looks like" and a "It should not look like this".

And a hint on which platform this has been seen is also helpful...

Comment: How it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/g3VBT/13/                          How it should look like: http://i.imgur.com/70PUg.jpg
It's a HTML webpage.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I still don't see the problem, especially if you adjust the width and padding after you changed the font-size, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are increasing the font-size,  you should change padding and width also.